# Questions about Michelson interferometer

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform, interference, interferometry

I have been doing experiment on Michelson experiment, but I don't quite understand why white light results in an interferogram with very few fringes, and why are they necessarily Gaussian?
I know that white light has a very short coherence length, but is there any reason behind this?
[image]

Comment: Could you please give some diagrams of your setup and show what the fringes are: are they fringes across a beam, or oscillations as a function of arm length. I think you'll get much more joy from all your questions if you add some clear diagrams.

Comment: You have asked several questions which I suspect are related, but each of which is essentially incomprehensible. Do you understand the basics of interference phenomena? Do you understand the basics of how a Michelson interferometer is supposed to work? If so, what *exactly* is tripping you up? Stack Exchange sites are not a good place to seek general education on broad topics like this; they work best when you understand *most* of what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry for causing misunderstanding, but this question really needs to be answered by people who have actually done the experiment.

Comment: Re Wetsavanna, sorry for that! I mean the fringes at the output port.